# using ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created angular directive with template:

```
<div class="directiveclass">
   <div ng-repeat="i in items">
       <input type="radio" ng-model="myvalue" value="{{$index}}">
   </div>    
</div>
```

The ng-model "myvalue" is part of the directive local scope:

```
.directive('mydirective', function()
{
    return {
        templateUrl: "path",
        scope: {},
        link : function(scope, el, attr)
        {
            scope.myvalue = 0;   
            scope.$watch('myvalue', function()
            {
                console.log('myvalue changed');
            });
        }
    };
}
```

I'm clicking on the the radio buttons elements, but "myvalue" value never change.

Any idea?

Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/r5jGL/

Comment: Manage to fix this problem, using: $parent.myval to access the directive scope.

Comment: Edit your post with the solution then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Since ng-repeat create new scope, I've changed the ng-model value to **$parent.myval** in order to access the directive scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.myvalue" value="{{$index}}">
```

This allows you to access ng-model as ng-repeat has created its own scope.

The directive does not need to be changed.